# Correct way to get uri of image embedded as resource in UWP class library

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UserControl in a class library for UWP. The usercontrol is going to be displaying signal level of the GPS.

I am using a `BitmapIcon` which displays the Signal level and it changes based on a signal level property. I am using a BitmapIcon so that I can change the foreground colour for themes etc.

Anyway, here is the xaml

```
<BitmapIcon Grid.Column="1" UriSource="{Binding GpsSignalState, Converter={StaticResource SignalImageConverter}}" 
                Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}"/>
```

It's bound to a property in the `ViewModel` and uses a converter to convert the signal to the correct image.

Here is the converter code.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if(value.GetType() != typeof(SignalStrength))
            return null;

        var signal = (SignalStrength)value;

        switch (signal)
        {
            case SignalStrength.Excellent:
                return new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png");
            case SignalStrength.VeryGood:
                return new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 3.png");
            case SignalStrength.Good:
                return new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 2.png");
            case SignalStrength.Valid:
                return new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 1.png");
            case SignalStrength.Bad:
                return new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 0.png");
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

As you can see the images are located in a folder Called `/Assets/Img/`

The images are set to build type as `Embedded Resource`.

I imagine someone may ask this so the assembly name is `Hardware.Sensors.GPS`

My issue is that the images never show. I get no error and I can put a break point in the converter to that it executes.

I have tried various ways of building a uri such as

```
Uri("/Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

and

```
Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png");
```

and

```
Uri("ms-appx:///Hardware.Sensors.GPS,component;/Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png");
```

but none seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: any particular reason they need to be "embedded resources" ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually I think the problem is not related to `Build Action`, you can set `Build Action` to:
[image]

I think the problem is with your Images, as you can see from the official document of [BitmapIcon class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon.aspx), in the "Remarks" part:

> The file that you use should be a solid image on a transparent background.

I replaced your images with some images downloaded from [here](http://icons.mysitemyway.com/3d-transparent-glass-icons-arrows/), it works. This `BitmapIcon` control will redraw the part filled with solid brush(un-transparent) of the source image with the `Foreground` color.

So, first method, you can replace your Images.

Sencond I think you can use a [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx) control like this:

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding GpsSignalState, Converter={StaticResource SignalImageConverter}}" />
```

There is no `Foreground` property of `Image` control, but it doesn't mean that you can't set a `Foreground` cover a `Image` control, you can for example do it like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Image Source="{Binding GpsSignalState, Converter={StaticResource SignalImageConverter}}" />
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.4"
               Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" />
</Grid>
```

But this method is unlike setting the `Foreground` property to `BitmapIcon`, if you insist replacing the transparent background with the `Foreground` color of the image, you should use `BitmapIcon`.

Comment: Still does not work for me. I deleted my images and downloaded ones from your link. I also added an Image control and put that side by side with the bitmapicon and bound both to the GpsSignalState. Neither of them showed an image. I also set the build action as you said and also tried the `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy if newer`. Still does not work. I get this feeling this can't be done in UWP

Comment: @Gaz83, I also tried this in UWP app, so it must can be done in UWP. I think there maybe some data binding problems. Maybe it's not related to the images, can you upload your sample?

Comment: But did you do this by creating a class library? I have just done an experiment and if I take the images, UserControl and the converter out of the class library and put them in my test project then everything seems to work fine. Bit difficult to upload as it a big library. Will see if I can strip it back.

Comment: @Gaz83, I think I know the problem now! I thought that only your usercontrol is in the class library. Your last comment told me that your images are also in the class library. I just tested, put the model class(for `SignalStrength`) and converter and usercontrol all in the class lib, but keep the images in the UWP app, it still works. The problem is actually related to the image's path in your converter, if your images are all in the Assets/Img folder in your class lib, the path should be like this: `return new Uri("ms-appx:///MyClassLibrary/Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 3.png");` .

Comment: Build Action = Content worked for me.  Then my resource was set to Source="ms-appx:///MySubFolderInProject/MyThemes/MyStyles.xaml"..  Thanks for the missing piece.  I had build action as embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Build Action** to `Content` and the **Copy to output directory** to `Do not copy` and your existing code should work.

Comment: this version should work Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png");

Comment: Nope, does not work. I have event swapped the BitmapIcon with an Image and still the same

Comment: does it work if you assign the image directly in your image? i.e. <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Img/Signal-Bars 4.png"/>